# OnMouseEnter in React on multiple divs doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, target

I have a problem with onMouseEnter in React. I want to expand just one card, and when I hover over one, each one is expanded in the same time. Please, help.

````
export default function Modules() {

  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <h5>title</h5>
      <Card>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
        >
        <p>Tele</p>
        {isShown && (
          <div onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
         <p>Logo</p>
         </div>
         </div>
        )}
      </Card>
           <h5>Title2</h5>
      <Card>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
        >
        <p>Tele</p>
        {isShown && (
          <div onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
         <p>Logo</p>
         </div>
         </div>
        )}
      </Card>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you're using the same state. If ifShown is true all the cards will show.. You can create an independent Card Component that manages his own state.

```
export const CardWrapper = ({ title}) => {
   const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

   return (
      <>
      <h5>{title}</h5>
      <Card>
        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
        >
        <p>Tele</p>
        {isShown && (
          <div onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}>
         <p>Logo</p>
         </div>
         </div>
        )}
      </Card>
   )
}
```

Then use it in your Modules component. Now each card manages is own state independently. I only pass the title as a prop because don't now what you need to use inside your card.

```
export default function Modules() {
   return (
      <CardWrapper title="title1" />
      <CardWrapper title="title2" />
   )
}
```